# linear-gradient color modify

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How can I modify the linear-gradient color with an another css file?

**background: linear-gradient(0deg, blue 12%, transparent 12%);**

It is possible or not? I can't modify the percentages, because it comes form javascript.

Comment: try `!important` in css file

Comment: can you clarify what you want please, I can't quite understand what you are after, sounds like a specificity or order issue

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If the bg comes from javascript you won't get any results by changing the css, since javascript runs after css rules have been applied (in most cases). You'll have to make another javascript code to change the percentages again.

Comment: linear-gradient is in inline style, because the javascript modify when i need.
But I need change color.

Answer (score 0):

I´m supposing you are trying to do a progress bar by CSS. I code this sentences for your purpose.

If you need to change the color or percent of gradient you just to call them from your javascript: Could be kind of:

```
var your_var_color1 = document.getElementById("color").value;    
document.getElementById("your_element").style.background = "linear-gradient(to right, " + your_var_color1 + " 0%, " + your_var_color1 + " " + (value1 – 20) + "%, rgba(255,255,255,1) " + value1 + "%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)";
```

Where:

-- 1st value (1st color), will be from 0% to value1

-- 2º value – when 1st color´s gradient start ((value1 - 20) to value1)

-- 3º value – when 2º color starts (value1)

-- 4º value - when 2 color finishes... (100% in this case)

I´m not setting value between 2º and 3º value, when first color finish and second starts which means will be setting automatically coming from others values...

Hope it help you...

Note: Using rgba(255,255,255,1) (white) for simulating progress bar with *color* for percent and *white* for not completed.

Edited: You can set the color by back-side (passing the value from the server) or setting it through the front (I suppose you are looking for this one). Just create an `<input type=text.../>`, where user introduce the color (you should check errors) or **combo box** with the colors predefined, and get its value in your js. Short example added.

Comment: I create an example.
https://jsfiddle.net/u36v7b56/4/
Thanks, for your help, but the inline color is a default value.

Comment: Do you? What do you mean? Where?

Comment: You´re wellcome. So what do you need now? :). The var called you_var_color set the first color you want...

Comment: I would like to keep default color value, but I would like to provide a chance that to be modifed from css.

Comment: Edited... @Developer

Comment: You don't understand me. I would like to use css, becuse it will be better than your hard coding option.

Comment: Is it possible with linear-gradient, or not?

Comment: Nope, sorry. But from where are you getting the colour value? The user have to define it somewhere... Or you can create diferent css´s class with different colour values and set it to the div but someone have to set it as well... You are setting the colour in your css (by javascript), linear gradient is a Css´s property. Finally, try to be polite, I´m trying to help you... :)

Comment: I can create many different css and when I need to change color just read otherone. (css making sense)

Comment: Well, just thinking. If you mean you want to modify your css properties dinamically (in execution time), you need to use, at least, javascript, razor, and so on... You can pass values to your css without it. Please, will be kind of you if you reward my efford and rate my answer and my comments as well if they help you... :) @Developer

Comment: But how you set what CSS class you want to set. You will need JS as well, and the user has to select it... @Developer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not want to rewrite my javascript. I just want to use css.
For example:
background: linear-gradient-color: red;

Comment: You can do it, but then if you want to change it, you must to use JS or similar... Mind you to rate my answer and/or comments? Thanks @Developer

Comment: Probably, you will want to join in our community. Helping others or asking new questions. Please, could you colaborate with all of us? I mean, rating answers and comments, with the time you will get benefits like to vote down an answer and so on... @Developer

Comment: Is your problem the biggest? Sorry, but I can't rating your answer, because I do not have enought reputation. I do not think you deserve the upvote. I do not understand why this is important to you.
I think "Thanks" is enough to you...

Comment: @Developer. You can accept the answer at least, you can raise the flags what help you. Really? Mother of God... ungrateful... I´m wasting MY TIME in explain you that you have to use JS for changing CSS dinamically, that is really BASIC... I´m wasting my time, during my work, in coding sentences for you.

Comment: @Developer.  It´s important for me because is how is working this community. Rewarding the efford of others (even more, in my job if any colleagues helps you in any way you use to buy a few beer to him). Dont deserve? I explain you why you cant do what you want, I show you how you can do it, ... What more you want? If you desire I can go to your home and give you a massage while I bring you a cold beer. Man... You are really cool guy. Keep your thanks in your pockets. Hoping (and preventing) not concur with you anymore... Good luck mate...